# Fetch _id of last created document of given type in Sanity

Tags: sanity, groq

In Sanity, for a given document type named `message`, how can I get the `_id` of the newest message document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Query

You can actually do that in a single query in [GROQ (Sanity's query language)](https://www.sanity.io/docs/data-store/how-queries-work):

```
*[_type == 'message'] | order(_createdAt desc) [0] ._id
```

### Query Explanation

This query has five parts.

1. `*[_type == 'message']`: select all documents of type `'message'`.
2. `|`: pipe the messages (so we can perform the rest of the operations)
3. `order(_createdAt desc)`: order the messages from newest to oldest (`_createdAt` is set automatically by Sanity when a document is created)
4. `[0]`: select the first message from the list (which is also the newest)
5. `._id`: select the `_id` of the newest message

To fetch another property, multiple properties or the entire message object, replace the last part of the query.

Comment: you're allowed to check off your own answer as the correct one. Makes it easier for others to identify a good solution.